# How do I open my BsModel on page load in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open my BsModel on page load on my Angular 8 Project. I have tried lot. But, Couldn't open my model. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ng-template #showPrivacyPop>
   <div class="modal-header">
       <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Create Pluck User</h4>
       <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
       jhgjhg
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

And my TS File:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ElementRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-filemanager',
  templateUrl: './filemanager.component.html'

})
export class FilemanagerComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('showPrivacyPop') public privacyPopup: TemplateRef<any>;

  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  config = {
    animated: true
  };


  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.privacyPopup);
  }

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    console.log(template);
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
  }

}
```

I don't know, how do I trigger the HTML to show on page load. Anyone please solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried calling int in `AfterViewInit` hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop `OnInit` method. `privacyPopup` will only be available on `AfterViewInit` hook. If it still gives you trouble, you can put it inside of a `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` just to throw it to the end of the line on the event loop queue.

Also, in angular 8, `@ViewChild` needs an extra argument (`{static: boolean}`). In Angular 9 it's optional as it defaults to `static: false`. Basically it tells the runtime to run the query after (`static: false`) or before (`static: true`) the first change detection cycle. Usually, you'll want it to be `false`, unless the query has any dependency that would be resolved only after the change detection runs.

```js
export class FilemanagerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild('showPrivacyPop', {static: false}) 
public privacyPopup: TemplateRef<any>;

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.openModal(this.privacyPopup);
}
```